# Verificar se valor do $_GET é 1 ou 2 e executar SQL UPDATE

Tags: php, post, pdo, get

Tenho o `$_GET['id']` e preciso verificar se o valor que ele pega da url `index.php?id=` é **1** ou **2**, e caso não seja nenhuma das alternativas executa um `die();`, caso seja **1** ou **2** atribui `$var = $_GET['id'];` e com um `if` chama cada uma das operações para cada `id` especifico e executa a operação SQL, a mesma não esta sendo executada.

**Código completo:**

```
    //Verifica se id é 1 ou 2
    if (!preg_match('/^[1-2]/', $_GET['id'])) {
        die();// not valid
    } else {
        $var = $_GET['id'];
    }

    //Recebe outros dados do index.php via post
    $pk = $_POST['pk'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=my_database;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
    //$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); #Estava em um exemplo, não sei se é necessario aqui

    //index.php?id=1
    if($var == "1"){
        //Executa SQL
        $sql = "UPDATE table_1 ".
        "SET :name=':value' ".
        "WHERE name_id = ':pk'";
    }   
    else
    {
        die("ERRO #1");
    }

    //index.php?id=2
    if($var == "2"){
        //Executa SQL2
        $sql = "UPDATE table_2 ".
        "SET :name=':value' ".
        "WHERE name_id = ':pk'";
    }   
    else
    {
        die("ERRO #2");
    }

    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(":pk", $pk);
    $statement->bindValue(":name", $name);
    $statement->bindValue(":value", $value);
    $count = $statement->execute();
```

**Debug**: Retorna `ERRO #2` quando deveria retornar `ERRO #1` na operação **1**. (Invertido)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para isto existe o `elseif`:

```
if($var == "1"){
   $sql = "UPDATE table_1 ".
      "SET :name=':value' ".
      "WHERE name_id = ':pk'";
}   
elseif($var == "2"){ // esta condição será testada se o if de cima for falso
   $sql = "UPDATE table_2 ".
      "SET :name=':value' ".
      "WHERE name_id = ':pk'";
}   
else
{
   die("ERRO #2");
}
```

### Aplicando ao seu código, e eliminando um `preg_match()` desnecessário:

Como você está apenas criando as strings $sql, basta começar o PHP com esta parte, que este if elimina completamente o uso do `preg_match()`, simplificando em muito a sua página.

```
$var = @$_GET['id']; // Usamos a @ pra suprimir alertas, já que o valor será verificado

if($var == "1"){
   $sql = "UPDATE table_1 ".
      "SET :name=':value' ".
      "WHERE name_id = ':pk'";
}   
elseif($var == "2")
{
   $sql = "UPDATE table_2 ".
      "SET :name=':value' ".
      "WHERE name_id = ':pk'";
}   
else
{
   die( 'ERRO' );
}

$pk = $_POST['pk'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$value = $_POST['value'];

$conn = new PDO( 'mysql:dbname=my_database;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '' );

$statement = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$statement->bindValue( ':pk', $pk );
$statement->bindValue( ':name', $name );
$statement->bindValue( ':value', $value );
$count = $statement->execute();
```

Se quiser simplificar mais ainda:

```
if($var == "1") {
   $sql = "UPDATE table_1 " // Estou assumindo que o nome da tabela possa ser outro
} elseif($var == "2") {
   $sql = "UPDATE table_2 " // Senao bastaria um 'UPDATE table_'.$var em vez de if
} else {
   die( 'ERRO' );
}
$sql .= " SET :name=':value' WHERE name_id = ':pk'"; // Completamos qualquer update aqui
```

### Conhecendo o `switch`:

Uma alternativa seria usar `switch`, mas seria exagero no seu caso, com apenas 2 ítens. Coloquei aqui só para que você saiba que é uma alternativa a `if` e `elseif`.

```
switch ($i) {
   case 1:
      //Executa SQL
      $sql = "UPDATE table_1 ".
      "SET :name=':value' ".
      "WHERE name_id = ':pk'";
      break;
   case 2:
      //Executa SQL2
      $sql = "UPDATE table_2 ".
      "SET :name=':value' ".
      "WHERE name_id = ':pk'";
      break;
   default:
       echo "#ERRO";
}
```

> Uma das vantagens do `switch` é quando você precisa fazer a mesma ação pra 2 ou 3 ítens seguidos, omitindo o `break`. Não é o seu caso.

Comment: Obrigado por editar, demostrou seu real interesse em ajudar. @Bacco, se possível poderia me explicar esse `$count`, se ele não é necessário ali, porque está? Para que serve ele exatamente?

Comment: @Florida pra mim não faz sentido uma variável com esse nome. o `execute` vai retornar `true` se a operação deu certo, ou `false` em caso contrário.

Answer (score 3):

Parece ser um erro de lógica no código. O código só aceita 2 valores no parametro `id`, segundo a função `preg_match`. Após essa linha o `$_GET['id']` só vai ser 1 ou 2, teoricamente se o `$_GET['id']` for 2, o `if ($var == "2")` nunca vai ser executado pois o script morre com a mensagem `ERRO #1`. Já se o $_GET['id'] for **1**, o script cai no primeiro `else` depois do `if ($var == "1")` retornando `ERRO #2`. Se você quer `ERRO #1` para quando o paramentro for **1**, deve inverter as mensagens.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos por partes...

Usar [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/preg_match) para esse tipo de verificação simples é o mesmo que matar uma formiga com uma bala de canhão. Com um pouquinho mais de Lógica de Programação, básico que qualquer programador deve ter, aplicado a sintaxe do PHP, você chegaria em algo como:

```
$id = ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : NULL )

if( $id != 1 || $id != 2 ) {

    die( 'Message Here' );
}
```

Por si só isso já deveria funcionar, permitindo, inclusive que aquele `else` do seu SQL Statement fosse removido. A não ser, é claro, que você precise mesmo distinguir as mensagens.

No entanto, isso equivale a tapar o Sol com uma peneira. O correto mesmo é primeiro de tudo você estruturar as rotas da sua Aplicação de forma lógica e hierárquica.

Se você começar agora a condicionar múltiplas possibilidade de SQL numa mesma rotina, não demora muito você terá uma única rotina de mais de 500 linhas, lotada de comentários (não que comentar seja algo ruim).

Então, se você tem duas ações distintas, separe-as, por exemplo:

Atual: `index.php?id=1` e `index.php?id=2`
Melhorado: `action1.php` e `action2.php`

> Nota: Apesar de "melhorado", ainda não é o ideal, mas o exemplo aqui é didático e visa unicamente esclarecer o conceito de separação.

Comment: Agradeço a sugestão, farei uso dela, porem nesse casso seria mais comodo ter as duas ações em um script, poupa trabalho caso alguma pequena alteração tenha que ser feita, nesse caso só faria 1 vez em vez de nos 2 arquivos.

Comment: Compreensível, mas espero que você não se esqueça no futuro :)