# pdo UPDATE não funciona

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estou tentando enviar alguns valores para o SQL, porem o PDO não funciona como deveria, ou estou esquecendo algo, sou novo no uso do PDO.

Exemplo de código funcional.

```
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=config_database;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
    $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE stream_table SET src='Funcional' WHERE start = '60'");
    $statement->execute();
```

Exemplo de código não funcional.(Tentei varias outras possibilidades sem sucesso)
(Não retorna erro, simplesmente não faz nada)

```
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=config_database;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
    //$value = $_POST['value'];              //A ideia real é pegar via POST
    $value = 'C:\sample.code';               //Simplificando o test
    $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE stream_table SET src='?' WHERE start = '60'");
    $statement->bindValue(":value", $value); //Testei com bindParam e bindValue
    $statement->execute();
```

Não sei se é devido aos apóstrofo ou outra coisa, segui vários exemplos contidos na internet e nem assim funciona, é *maligno*.

Como posso executar esse comando de forma funcional?

[Talvez esse post aqui do SO-pt ajude.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20804/verificar-se-valor-do-get-%C3%A9-1-ou-2-e-executar-sql-update/20816#20816)

**@Edit**

> NOTA do erro: O Não posso usar placeholders para nome de tabelas ou colunas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando utilizar `?` no bindValue coloque a ordem do argumento e variável:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE stream_table SET src = ? WHERE start = ? ");
$statement->bindValue(1, $value);
$statement->bindValue(2, $id);
```

Com as marcações (`:nome`) a ordem não importa

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE stream_table SET src = :value WHERE start = :id ");
$statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
$statement->bindValue(':value', $value);
```

Para exibir o erro adicione o argumento opcional no construtor além de PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION exitem [outras formas](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) de tratar o erro.

```
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn = new PDO('mysql:dbname=config_database;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', '', $options);

try {
   //....
   $statement->execute();
} catch(Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: É, está funcionando, meus agradecimentos por dedicar seu tempo. Talvez por causa de estar dentro do try, não sei, vou tentar descobrir pelo menos onde errei para que não aconteça novamente.

Comment: Olhando o link da outra questão, nomes de tabelas e de colunas não podem ser substituidos por `?` ou `:marcação`. A utilização de prepared statements evita sql injection não adicione aspas nos valores apenas indique as marcações.

Comment: O Não posso usar **placeholders** para nome de tabelas ou colunas, por isso mesmo tudo estando certo o `:name` impedia a operação, solução, usei `switch` para verificar dos dados vindos e setar o `:name` manualmente impedindo um provável ataque sql, o sql ficou `SET $bypassname=:value`. (PS: usar src como você colocou não era viável pois os dados são dinâmicos)